# .Net scheduled tasker

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

I remember working in a company where we had a scheduled task manager. It was a windows service running on several machines, synchronized in the DB, that we used for running offline batch processes.

Now I found myself having to do it all over in my current workplace. Is there a framework that you recommend for jump starting my development?

Constraints:

- It should be easily deployed to several environments. For example: Windows scheduled task deployment is complicated when done manually.
- It should not start a new task when the same task is already in progress.
- A task crushing will not crush the scheduler.

Comment: Have you tried Windows Services ?

Comment: Yes, the solution I am looking for probably will be a windows service. But I don't want to spend a lot of time writing the task scheduling engine from scratch. I prefer focusing in the task itself.

Comment: Have you tried a SQL Server Agent Job ?

Comment: Thought about that, but I'm not OK with the DB machine spending it's CPU and memory on CLR logic.

Comment: C#/VB code that has specific business that is ran directly from MSSQL DB. (Sometimes people write functions in .Net that perform string actions for SQL scripts)

Comment: And the option of writing the solution entirely in SQL is bad for maintainance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm so happy to read that you don't want to write you own scheduler. I've seen it done several times and it *always* becomes over-complicated and difficult to maintain (i.e. technical debt).

I would highly recommend [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

Hangfire is deployed as an ASP.NET application and can use Azure for running the jobs. It has automatic retry logic, error reporting, and a nice dashboard that you can use to configure task and see what is happening.

[image: Hangfire Dashboard]

Answer (score 2):

I had sucess using the [Quartz .Net Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net). It began as a port of the Java *Quartz Scheduler* and it is activley developed. It should be easy to fullfill your requriements with it.

Among others it features Job Persistence (via ADO.NET Job Store (AdoJobStore)) fine grained Job Scheduling and Failover mechanisms.

Try reading [the tutorials](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/index.html) to get an understanding first.